# Realtime updates between C# desktop app, mobile app and SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, mobile, signalr

Can anyone explain the best practice communication flow for a multi-app solution I am currently working on. I will have a MS SQL server database running. This database will be accessed and updated by one or more windows desktop applications and mobile devices(android, iOS and Windows). Whenever any changes are made to the database, the clients should be updated in real time to reflect. The desktop applications are most important and need to be updated with as little delay as possible. The mobile apps on the other hand can tolerate a delay of a minute or so.

My idea is connect the desktop application to the server using signalR, the database will then notify any connected clients of the update via SQLDependency. For the mobile side, I was planning for the server to send notifications to the mobile devices, where upon receipt of the notification, the mobile device would requery the SQL Server (via web service) to update itself.

I guess my question is, is this the best (standard) way to go about this or is there a better/quicker/more robust way to achieve this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create an API in C# and host in on IIS.  Your desktop app (be it web or native) will then use RESTful calls to the APIs.

The API's, hosted on IIS would communicate to SQL Server.  For database operations, you would have CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete).  You would expose a GUID (generated using NEWID() in sql server) to each CRUD method and supply serialized data.  E.g. perhaps XML or JSON POSTed to the API.

In my view (and practice), this is the Best option.  It is truly global, and the API's can "talk" to any client app capable of making HTTP requests.

So the system becomes:

SQL Server > API/IIS > Client (Android, iOS, JS, Java, Windows, Unix, Mac, etc)

Benefits here also are:

1. SSL out of the box
2. RESTful transactions - can use oAuth or write your own (proprietary is harder to hack!)
3. Highly scalable - IIS support 100's of transactions per second
4. Do not need to open port 1433 (SQL port) to web (which will open you to hacking).  API uses port 443 (HTTPS)
5. If you write your API using C#, you have many serialze/deserialize functions out of the box.

Hope this answers your question.